# RMSE credible intervals for Gaussian Processes

Tags: gaussian-process, mse, credible-interval

I am trying to calculate a credible interval for the predictions I obtain from a GP regression problem. My objective is to compare the predictive performance of two models.

I got out-of-sample predictions for the latent function employing the predictive equations for GPs. After that I calculate the MSE and the RMSE because I know the true function. Now, I was asked to calculate a credible interval for MSE and RMSE. I am confused on how to do that. Is it correct to use the predictive variance and obtain and upper and lower limit of the MSE and RMSE?

Answer (score 1):

MSE and RMSE are usually better suited to support vector machines in which you can specify a loss function which matches the loss function you wish to optimise for (ie MSE / RMSE). A GP on the other hand offers a probabilistic model which offers a mean and variance for each predictive point. The goal is not to minimise the MSE or RMSE between the mean and the true value, but rather to maximise the predictive performance of the model. This is achieved when, for example, 30% of observations lie in the 30% interval of the predictive gaussian - and that of 50% in a 50% interval and so on.

Comment: So, you suggest not to employ RMSE to compare two models? Say, I have a regression GP with gaussian kernel vs a regression GP with Matern kernel. I have seen papers employing these measurements as a mean of comparing its performance. Additionally, how can you measure if, in fact, 90% of your realisations lie in the interval?
thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you first consider what you think the noise / loss function should be - are you in fact hoping to to minimise RMSE / MSE, if so use a SVM. If a GP is in fact correct then you want to compare the marginal likelihoods. You probably optimised the negative log marginal likelihood while doing training - this is the probability of the data given your prior. Simply compare these values to see which is a better fit! (higher probability the better!)